# PHP Help with regular expressions... error: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regexp in php. I am just trying to do a simple preg_match on two strings. Here is my code:

```
$pattern = '\\w*'.strtolower($CK);

if(preg_match($pattern, $rowName, $matches) == true)
            {
                echo 'true';

            }
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /home/daskon/public_html/reflexInvestor_dev/php/rss_functions.php on line 319
```

I imagine it's because I need to put something after the pattern, but I can;t seme to find what that is. When I try the same pattern in a regexp tester, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the pattern in delimiting characters (I like to use `#` since I rarely need them inside of the regex):

```
if (preg_match('#' . $pattern . '#', $rowName, $matches)) {
```

(You also don't need the `== true`, it's redundant since that's what the if does anyway internally...)

Comment: Interesting; I use `#` too, and generally people ask me why I'm the only person in the world to use it

Comment: I don't have anything against other delimiters, I just like `#`...  I don't use any of the regex meta-characters, so `^`, `$`, etc are out.  And as for `/`, I just find that I need that character more often than I need `#` (inside a regex at least).  So I like using `#` (and make it a habit)...

Comment: Thanks!

So how come if I am matching the keyword 'mcdonald' to 'mcdonalds breakfast' using this regular expression I get no results?  I get other results that match, but not that one.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact contents of those strings?  No case changes?  And I'm assuming that you're talking about `$CK` has `mcdonald`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am getting results. Was echoing out the wrong thing :p.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the pattern in a [**delimiter**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) that marks the beginning and end. Any "non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace" character works. `/` is very common, so:

```
$pattern = '/\\w*' . strtolower($CK) . '/';
```

The reason for the delimiter is you can include [pattern modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in the pattern, but they appear *after* the delimiter