# PHP preg_match for ending tag

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-match

I need to use preg_match to check if a line is ending with /> or / > 
I have created a function, that contains the followling line

```
if (!preg_match('\/>$', $str)) {
```

But it do not work, as it comes with this error

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Help with regular expressions... error: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464180/php-help-with-regular-expressions-error-delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added an optional space between \ and >.

```
if (!preg_match('|\/ ?>$|', $str)) {
```

Comment: Thanks :D 
I have seen, that PHP needs | or something similar

Comment: -0.00001 for not quite answering the question as asked - the asker's problem was lack of delimiters around the pattern which the answer doesn't explicitly mention. i'll grant that the answer was helpful with regard to the optional space.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

You can use `|` for example

```
if (!preg_match('|\/>$|', $str)) {
```